# The model backing the 'SisContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider, entity-framework-migrations

When I try to Login with details that are available in database(SIS) I get this error.

```
The model backing the 'SisContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database. Thing is Database(SIS) was manually added using add existing item and not generated automatically.
```

My SisContext looks like this

```
public class SisContext : DbContext
    {
        //protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        //{
        //    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IncludeMetadataConvention>();
        //}
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BusinessUnit> BusinessUnits { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LicenseHolder> LicenseHolders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<License> Licenses { get; set; }

        public SisContext():base("SIS")
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<SisContext>(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have another class called `DataContextInitializer` which looks like this

```
public class DataContextInitializer:DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SisContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(SisContext context)
        {
        WebSecurity.Register("Demo", "123456", "demo@demo.com", true, "Demo", "Demo");
        Roles.CreateRole("Admin");
        Roles.AddUserToRole("Demo", "Admin");
        }
    }
```

In my AccountController the Login method is as follows;

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
    {

        //
        // GET: /Account/
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            if(Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

`ValidateUser` method that is being used in above `Login` action is in class `CodeFirstMembershipProvider` class which inherits from `MembershipProvider`

```
 public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                return false;
            }
            using (SisContext Context = new SisContext())
            {
                AspNetUser User = null;
                User = Context.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(Usr => Usr.Username == username);//error mentioned above is shown here
                if (User == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (!User.IsApproved)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (User.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                String HashedPassword = User.Password;
                Boolean VerificationSucceeded = (HashedPassword != null && Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(HashedPassword, password));
                if (VerificationSucceeded)
                {
                    User.PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess = 0;
                    User.LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    User.LastActivityDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                }
                else
                {
                    int Failures = User.PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess;
                    if (Failures < MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts)
                    {
                        User.PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess += 1;
                        User.LastPasswordFailureDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    }
                    else if (Failures >= MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts)
                    {
                        User.LastPasswordFailureDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        User.LastLockoutDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        User.IsLockedOut = true;
                    }
                }
                Context.SaveChanges();
                if (VerificationSucceeded)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

in my web config I have added my custommembershipProvider

```
 <membership defaultProvider="CodeFirstMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CodeFirstMembershipProvider" type="Sorama.CustomAuthentication.CodeFirstMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SisContext" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CodeFirstRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CodeFirstRoleProvider" type="Sorama.CustomAuthentication.CodeFirstRoleProvider" connectionStringName="SisContext" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <!--<httpModules>
      <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </httpModules>-->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="180" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SISContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\SIS.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried following this link.... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621 . I am using MVC3 and EF6.0.0.1
I had the same problem, but by Enabling Code First Migrations the error disappeared.